# Assigning onclick function to dynamically created button

Tags: jquery, button

Following the best practises, with callback functions and dealing with the initially parent loaded div, I did this:

```js
$("#buttons_div").
html('<input type="button" value="Click me" id="button1" />', function() {
  $("#buttons_div").
  on("click", "#button1", function() {
    alert("alert")
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="buttons_div">
</div>
```

Why this doesn't work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This won't work. The two statements should be separate. You cannot pass the event handler as an argument to the `.html()` function. You need to do this way:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#buttons_div").html('<input type="button" value="Click me" id="button1" />');
  $("#buttons_div").on("click", "#button1", function() {
    alert("alert")
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="buttons_div">
</div>
```

Comment: I thought about that. But how can I assure that the event handler is assigned only after the method .html is finished? Shouldn't be somewhere a callback?

Comment: or considering that since `.html` has no callbacks, is the code executed always sequentially?

Comment: @JoãoPimentelFerreira HTML code is sequential. It's not asynchronous. `:)`

Comment: Yes, I know, I was just wondering that the method `.html` could not be :) thank you

Answer (score 2):

For dynamically generated elements direct JavaScript functions doesnot works for the element. So you have to use the parent element of that dynamically generated element or you can use document instead of that parent element.

```
$(function() {
$("#buttons_div").html('<input type="button" value="Click me" id="button1" 
/>');
$(document).on("click", "#button1", function() {
alert("alert")
});
});
```

or You can do this using this too:

```
$(function() {
$("#buttons_div").html('<input type="button" value="Click me" id="button1" 
/>');
$("#buttons_div").on("click", "#button1", function() {
alert("alert")
});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are nesting the click event inside the `html()` function.

```js
$("#buttons_div").html('<input type="button" value="Click me" id="button1" />');
$("#buttons_div").on("click", "#button1", function(){
  alert("alert")
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="buttons_div">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I thought about that. But how can I assure that the event handler is assigned only after the method .html is finished? Shouldn't be somewhere a callback?